# ContentProvider: How to cancel a previous call to delete()?

Tags: android-contentprovider, cancellation

I'm using a custom [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). For querying, there is a [CancellationSignal](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CancellationSignal.html) (API 16+) which can be used to cancel a previous call to [query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29).

My question: How can I archive that with `delete()`? For clarification, my custom provider manages files on SD card, and so I want to be able to cancel delete operation inside my provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a simple solution.

For example, for every call to `query()`, we put a parameter pointing to the task ID, and use a [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) to hold that ID, like:

```
...
private static final SparseBooleanArray _MapInterruption = new SparseBooleanArray();

...
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor = ...

    int taskId = ... // obtain task ID from uri
    boolean cancel = ... // obtain cancellation flag from uri
    if (cancel) {
        _MapInterruption.put(taskId, true);
        return null; // don't return any cursor
    } else {
        doQuery(taskId);
        if (_MapInterruption.get(taskId)) {
            _MapInterruption.delete(taskId);
            return null; // because the task was cancelled
        }
    }

    ...
    return cursor;
}// query()

private void doQuery(int taskId) {
    while (!_MapInterruption.get(taskId)) {
        ... // do the task here
    }
}// doQuery()
```

Usage:

- To query:

  ```
  ...
  getContentResolver().query("content://your-uri?task_id=1", ...);
  ```
- To cancel:

  ```
  ...
  getContentResolver().query("content://your-uri?task_id=1&cancel=true", ...);
  ```

For a complete working solution, have a look at [android-filechooser](http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/).

The advantage is you can use this technique in Android… 1+ and for other methods such as `delete()`, `update()`... While [CancellationSignal](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CancellationSignal.html) is only available in API 16+ and is limited to only `query()`.